# Video Could not play on ajax call

Tags: ajax, html, video, laravel-5

In laravel, Video tag could not play new source video path ajax it always plays with old source video.

After restarting browser it plays video properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            $('video').attr('src', data.newurl);
            $('video').get(0).load();
        },
     });
});
```